# Android Spinner and findViewbyID

Tags: xml, spinner, r.java-file

I am trying to create a spinner and am following the instructions from a you tube tutorial. This is what I have in my XML:

```
  <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1" />
```

I am trying to refer to it in the MainActivity in the following way:

```
spinner =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

But I am getting the following message:

spinner1 cannot be resolved or is not a field

I know this is to do with the fact that spinner is not being created in the R.Java file, but I do not understand why it is not being created, or how to fix it.

I am having a similar problem with the strings file:

```
  <String-array name ="days">

        <item>Sunday</item>
        <item>Monday</item>
                <item>Tuesday</item>
                <item>Wednesday</item>
                <item>Thursday</item>
                <item>Friday</item>
                <item>Saturday</item>

    </String-array>
```

the Java code is:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.days, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

and I get the following error in the Strings file:

error: Found tag String-array where item is expected

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning the project and then rebuilding it.

Answer (score 1):

your code :
        spinner =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

Corrected code :

```
    Spinner myspinner =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
               ^(instance)                            ^(spinner id)
```